# Count only rows with data, without using fixed column descriptors

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, formulas

[picture demonstration of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXr51.png)

I want to count only the rows that contain at least one cell of data (text OR numbers), within a specified range of columns. However, I don't want to specify the range of columns using their fixed column letter names, but using the text in row 1 as the column header. (This Row 1 text is set up to be variable, so it will be different for every individual usage of the workbook that I am creating, so I can't just plug in the fixed column names)

Ideally I want a formula (rather than a Macro/VBA code) to put into a cell on another sheet. If I use a Macro/VBA then it will decrease the user-friendliness of the workbook I'm creating (it's a tool for my non-technical team to automate quantitative survey data analysis, with variable, but predictable, data inputs).

I have found many tips and formulas to count only the rows that contain at least one cell of data, using arrays, etc, but none that allow this variable column functionality

For example, the values in row 1 will read: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q3.2, Q3.3, Q3.4, Q4, Q4.2, Q5, etc., where the number of columns with decimals allocated will vary depending on previous inputs and will occupy different columns each time the workbook is used. Now, say for example I want to look at just columns relating to Q3 (so including Q3.2, Q3.3, Q3.4, etc). I am totally lost on how to do this without using fixed column names. (See image for demonstration).

Any help much appreciated! And please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Look into `UsedRange`

Comment: So you want to check `1. Row 1 heading matches text (fully or partially)` and `2. Row 2 onwards there's some data for matched columns`. Is that what you want? What is your attempt?

Comment: Hi Shrivallabha.redj, thanks for your comment. Yes row 1 heading will match some text (either in the formula, or matching a nearby cell/range of cells, specified like an index/match), and row 4 downwards will be the rows I want to count. I just can't use A:A,B:B etc. as my array/range as the data will be falling under different columns each time. My attempt so far has been to look up forums for formulas/tips/etc but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to look at just columns relating to Q3 ...

I am unclear on what good looking at them will do but this is how to list and sum the related data underneath.

In the following sample data image, put this into L2 then fill right and down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$I2, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN($A:$I)/(LEFT($A$1:$I$1, LEN($K2))=$K2), COLUMN(A:A))), TEXT(,))
```

For the sum in L6,

```
=SUMIFS(A2:I2, A$1:I$1, K6&"*")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeepeed, thanks for your answer, but it's not a sum or count of cells I am after. I want to count the number of rows that have at least one cell of data in them (not number of cells). We will be working with data that will have hundreds of rows, many blanks. I've added a screenshot to my original message to be clearer. Let me know if still unclear.

Comment: So use the methods I've demonstrated to get the results you want.

Comment: Hi, I've used your methods and I did not get the results. I think you must have misunderstood me. In your example above, the formula would give an answer '2' because there are 2 rows with data in them below Q3/Q3.2/Q3.3/Q3.4. The answer would be 2 for Q1, Q2, Q4/Q4,2 and Q5 also. Please refer to the image I uploaded for an example. Your method seems to just provide references to a particular row per Q number and then a sum. I am not wanting to sum any data (I could expect either text or numbers coming up). Just a COUNT of the rows that contain data.

Comment: I've updated the image to be more explicit about what I want. Hope it is all clear. Thanks!

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: I think you've given me an opportunity to retype all of your sample data while you've demonstrated not a whiff of original effort.